# Salvando id de um form select

Tags: php, cakephp

Eu preciso salvar o `id` de um `select`, mas no meu `select`, está mostrando o nome do item, então no caso eu preciso salvar no banco de dados o `id` deste item.

Form:

```php
<?=$this->Form->create('Acomodacao');?>
                        <?= $this->Form->input('acomodacoes',array(
                            'type' => 'select',
                            'options' => $acomodacoes,
                            'class' => 'form-control',
                            'empty' => false
                            )); 
                        ?>
                        <?= $this->Form->input('semanas', array(
                            'options' => $semanas,
                            'empty' => 'Até',
                            'class' => 'form-control'
                        )); ?>
```

Controller:

```php
$acomodacoes = $this->Navigation->find('list',array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'parent_id' => null,
    ),
    'fields' => array(
        'Navigation.id',
        'Navigation.nome',
    ),
));
$semanas = array();          
for ($i = 1; $i < 49; $i++) {
    $semanas[$i] = "$i semana" . ($i > 1 ? "s" : "");
}
```

As semanas salvam direito, mas o `id` no meu banco de dados sempre fica igual á 0, pois ele está tentando salvar o nome.

O meu *save* do form está assim:

```php
if ($this->request->is('post')){
        $this->Acomodacao->save($this->request->data);
}
```

Comment: Primeiro, você tem [dois usuários](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/23821/roberto-schon)? Segundo, qual sua estrutura da tabela `acomodacoes`? Imagino que você tenha um campo `semanas` nesta tabela, certo? E como assim as semanas salvam direito e o `id` não? Ao que parece, você só precisa do `id` para salvar.

Comment: no select de acomodações, está retornando , Flat,Hotel,Casa, eu preciso ao invéz de salvar o nome deles, o id.

Minha tabela tem 3 campos. id(AI) acomodacoes(INT),semanas(INT).

Como acomodações está INT, está salvando valor 0, pois o que o form está retornando é string, eu preciso que na hora de salvar, ao invez do cake tentar salvar string no campo de acomodações, ele salve o id da string que está no select.

Comment: Certo, então o problema é com o campo `acomodacoes` e não `semanas` como deixou a entender na sua pergunta.

Comment: Eu disse, que as semanas, estão salvando corretamente, mas na hora de salvar o id da acomodaçao, está salvando como 0.